# Face detection in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I am using OpenCV's face detection. It works fine when it comes to drawing a little rectangle around each face. But I'd like to know whether there is an easy way to get, for each pixel, the probability that the pixel belongs to any face (for example, the max over all scales of the cascade)... ie., the continuous version of these littles rectangles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use kernel methods to go pixel by pixel and convolve a ROI with a general face template in order to obtain the likelihood that each pixel belongs to a face.

Answer (score 2):

Most algorithms consider face detection as a binary classification problem, i.e. the scanning windows are classified as faces or non-faces. You can look into some bayesian models if you want probabilty of faces, but even they don't operate on pixel level. Also why do you want pixel probabilities anyway?